# Prevent a duplicate STATION ID from appearing

Tags: vb.net

I have a form currently which accepts a SAMPLE_ID from the user, among other fields. The problem is that although this is a required field, the user can input a duplicate value for a future point he/she inputs. In another form, I found a way around this by auto-incrementing and auto-populating this ID - but on this form, this isn't allowed.

What would be a way to check, upon saving a second point, that the SAMPLE_ID is unique?

Label & TextBox for SAMPLE_ID:

```
                <Label x:Name="lblSampleStationID" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="[Sample Station ID]"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ValidationError}">
                            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource resErrorTemplate}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=txtSampleStationID, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtSampleStationID" Text="{Binding SAMPLE_ID}" Style="{StaticResource txtSingleline}" MaxLength="20"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

Button Save:

```
Private Async Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        If Await _feature.AddorUpdateFeature Then
            Me.Close()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Constants.WriteToErrorLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType.Name,
                        System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name,
                        ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have permissions to edit/change the database? (or wherever this data is being stored)

Comment: I do yep - can query it to search for a duplicate. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Would you consider the reverse?  If you add a constraint to that column in the DB, to prevent duplicates, you would have to detect a complaint/warning/error from the DB, about a constraint violation, but then you could be sure duplicates are prevented.

Comment: Also, from your description, it sounds like you want Sample_ID to be unique, like a primary key.  Does the user really need to be responsible for this, or could it be better to use an auto-number (calculated by the DB) for that column?

Comment: I did accomplish the auto-increment on another form for the app, but on this form, no auto-increment is allowed. The recipient of the app wants the user to input it.